# Gitlab-omnibus not running on 8080

Tags: apache, gitlab

i want gitlab to run on port 8080 because i have apache running on port 80 and want to setup a proxy for gitlab.

but after installing gitlab using the commands:

```
wget https://downloads-packages.s3.amazonaws.com/debian-7.6/gitlab_7.5.2-omnibus.5.2.1.ci-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
sudo apt-get install postfix
sudo dpkg -i gitlab_7.5.2-omnibus.5.2.1.ci-1_amd64.deb
```

and i changed /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb to contain:

```
external_url "http://gitlab.mydomain.com:8080"
```

and executed the commands:

```
sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
sudo gitlab-ctl restart
```

But i still cannot reacht gitlab on "http://gitlab.mydomain.com:8080" 
An i could not find a solution to fix my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to my problem was that i did not have git installed.
this i because i followed the instructions on https://about.gitlab.com/downloads/
using dfebian 7 as that is my os. it never said that i had to have git installed on my system before installing gitlab.
 (it was wrong of me to assume that gitlab would install this for me and it was an easy fix)

Comment: git [is installed](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/config/software/git.rb) with the package, I don't think this was the reason.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check your [`gitlab.yml` config file](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/config/gitlab.yml.example#L21):

```
## GitLab settings
gitlab:
## Web server settings (note: host is the FQDN, do not include http://)
host: localhost
port: 80 # Set to 443 if using HTTPS, see installation.md#using-https for additional HTTPS configuration details
```

Changing the port to 8080 should help.

Comment: Thanks for the response but in the gitlab.yml the port was already changed to port: 8080

Comment: If the port is already set to `8080` in `gitlab.yml` run `gitlab-ctl reconfigure` in order to apply this parameter

Answer (score 0):

There was recently introduced a [template](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/files/gitlab-config-template/gitlab.rb.template) for all possible settings in `gitlab.rb`. What you want to add is

```
nginx['redirect_http_to_https_port'] = 8080
```

and then run reconfigure.

See https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/9e97671d8dee3ea6a7bbb99347ad279b65689f28/files/gitlab-config-template/gitlab.rb.template#L316